# Changing html classes using jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, web

I have many elements with the same class name such as:

```
<li class="contact" id="content">
 // some content here....
</li>
 .
 .
<li class="contact active" id="content">
 // some content here....
</li>
 .
 .
<li class="contact" id="content">
 // some content here....
</li>
 .
 .
<li class="contact" id="content">
 // some content here....
</li>
 .
 .
```

All the classes have the same name except for one which says 'contact active'.
This element in the page will be highlighted when the user clicks on it. I've wrote a jquery script to change the class name when clicked on here:

```
$('#content').click(function() {
$(this).removeClass('contact');
$(this).addClass('contact active');
});
```

But the problem is, it only searches for one matching id and then it stops. So, except for the first element all the other elements have no effect. Also I would like to change the name of the already active class ('contact active') back to just 'contact' when I click on the other elements.

Comment: id should not be repeated. You should use class instead. Also I suggest to use toggleClass jQuery function

Comment: `id` should be unique, you cannot have more than 1 element that has the same `id`

Comment: Yes but these classes are being printed on a loop using php.

Comment: you can use class '.contact'

Comment: I suggest changing the PHP loop so that ids are unique and then attach the event via a class, e.g. "contact".

Comment: Use a different id like contact1 , contact2  this can be done by a loop

Comment: Also why remove contact and then add it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have is that `id` attributes *need* to **always** be unique within the DOM. If you want to group elements with a common identifier, use a `class`.

You can then select the elements by that class and call `toggleClass()` on them. Note that you also don't need to remove/add the `contact` class either.

> the last problem is there can be only one active class at a time so the other active class should get unselected.

In that case you can simply call `removeClass()` on all the `.content` elements but the one which was clicked. Try this:

```js
$('.content').click(function() {
  $('.content').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="content contact">
    Content...
  </li>
  <li class="content contact active">
    Content...
  </li>
  <li class="content contact">
    Content...
  </li>
  <li class="content contact">
    Content...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My bad, Great this works! but the last problem is there can be only one active class at a time so the other active class should get unselected.

Answer (score 3):

IDs must be unique. Your id selector is assigning click event to only first element in matched set.

You need to modify the click event to have class selector and not ID Selector:

```
 var $contactDiv = $('.contact');
 $contactDiv.click(function() {
  $contactDiv.removeClass('active'); // remove all active
  $(this).addClass('active'); // add it back on this object
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.contact').click(function() {
 $('.contact').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #000;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="contact">
    Content 1...
  </li>
  <li class="contact">
    Content 2...
  </li>
  <li class="contact">
    Content 3...
  </li>
  <li class="contact">
    Content 4...
  </li>
</ul>
```

The main issue is `id`. `id` should be unique on a page. As you are using `id="content"` multiple times on a single page. Now you need to modify your jQuery as:

```
$('.contact').click(function() {
 $('.contact').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```